# Where is the Operating System files stored in Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have just switched from Windows to Linux, and wanted to know where the files of operating system are stored in Linux. As windows stored the OS files on C drive and Linux has no drive options, so where do it stores the OS files in it? And does the Linux support only one drive system, the complete hard disk?

Comment: What type of Linux are you using? For example, Ubuntu

Comment: What specific OS files are you looking for? The low-level kernel source code may not be on your system, but can be found [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). You can clone that repo and go through the files yourself and you can even compile it and use it as your kernel. The kernel executable is a `vmlinuz` file that you can find in `/boot/`. There are other OS files that that could be in `/etc`, all depends what specifically you're looking for.

Comment: Check out the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site for Linux questions not related to programming (and limit one question per post). You can also look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to see which files go where. Rest assured that Linux supports multiple disks and partitions.